# Tuples without dictionaries

Tags: python, tuples, histogram

I want to make a python function.

My solution, which I know is incomplete and wrong, is as follows:

```
s = [11.3, 16.1, 7.5, 4.3, 12.4, 10.3, 18.7, 9.3, 18.5] 
x = dict([(a, 'Pass' if a>9.5 else 'Fail' if a<9.5 else 'Fail') for a in s])

print (x)
```

The problem is that the program cannot have any input statements, and functions must return values ​​and not write them. Another situation is that I can't use "dict", that is, dictionaries, but only tuples.

Can anyone correct me the code for the question in question, using tuples and counted cycles, as well as commenting the most important part for me to understand?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why `print` something if u can `return` it? And use `sys.args` as input

Comment: So, you will have a function.  That function will create an empty histogram (`histo = [0]*21`).  You will loop through each score and bump the appropriate cell.  At the end, you return the histogram list.  What's so hard about that?

Comment: And I don't know what you mean by `counted cycles`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def histogram(s):
    hist = []
    for i in range(21):
        hist.append(len([x for x in s if x >= i and x < i+1]))
    return tuple(hist)


s = [11.3, 16.1, 7.5, 4.3, 12.4, 10.3, 18.7, 9.3, 18.5] 
print(histogram(s))
```

Output:
`(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0)`